# Paytm verify checksum issue

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway, paytm

[Paytm Verify checksum](http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/paytm_api_doc?target=interpreting-response-sent-by-paytm) keeps failing in node.js. we used this [library](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_NodeJs) from paytm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify checksum was failing because of the date format issue.

Paytm uses the date format as “YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.S” whereas we were getting TXNDATE as

```
Mon Mar 27 2017 17:00:37 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

or

```
  TXNDATE: 2017-03-27T17:00:37.000Z,
```

So we need to convert TXNDATE into the above mentioned format using moment.js

```
params.TXNDATE = moment(new Date(params.TXNDATE)).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S")
```

Comment: I am getting date format as "2019-07-08 14:19:12.0" , I think it looks fine , can you please look here too

Comment: It's not working for me. I am getting an error like "Error while verifying checksum".